# Solving an equation of the type $axe^{qx} + be^{rx} + cx + d = 0$

Tags: exponential-function

I need to solve an equation of the type,
$axe^{qx} + be^{rx} + cx + d = 0$

I tried but couldn't solve it.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this(for x)?

Thanks

Comment: The solution is $d=-axe^{qx}-be^{rx}-cx$.  Or did you want to solve for $x$?

Comment: I want to solve for x. a,b,c,d,q and r are constants.

Comment: You have to specify the variable to which you want to solve.

Comment: Why do you want to solve this? How would *you* solve $e^x+x=0$?

Comment: Only numerical methods would do it. If you want me to elaborate, post values of your choice for the different constants.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  The problem is these constants may take different values. I need a general solution. I also was thinking about a numerical method but then can we get a general solution?

Comment: Provided that there is **one** solution, the problem should be very simple with Newton.

Comment: Why one solution? Sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: So an interesting question is then, "Under what conditions does the equation have a *unique* sokution?"

Answer (score 2):

The equation as stated does not admit a symbolic (closed-form) solution. The following variations of it *can* be solved analytically:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
axe^{qx}+cx & = 0 \quad \text{(Solution: } \frac{1}{q}\log(-\frac{c}{a}) \text{)} \\
axe^{qx}+d & = 0 \quad \text{(Solution: } \frac{1}{q}W(-\frac{dq}{a}) \text{, where W is the Lambert W function)} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

More general forms such as the one you provided are out of reach from an analytical standpoint, but may easily be tackled numerically with any variation of [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), especially since the derivatives can be computed analytically and therefore rapidly evaluated to high precision. Additionally, the optimization function is convex for many parameter choices, so you can expect rapid convergence to a zero without problems.

Comment: So, simply it is not possible to have a general solution for this using any method?

Comment: @TavionPotter: Not an analytical solution, no. But any sufficiently advanced numerical method will converge to at least **one** solution (though not necessarily all of them).

Comment: Could you recommend any such method? Sorry I am not very familiar with numerical methods.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with numerical equation solving, you'll be best served with the built-in solvers of any computer algebra system (MATLAB, Octave, Mathematica, ...). These systems will apply sophisticated meta-algorithms that are pretty much guaranteed to find not just one but even multiple (all?) solutions.

Comment: Will it be possible to get a solution from them without having specific values for a,b,c.. ?

Comment: No. Numerical methods require numbers, they cannot work with symbols. You might be able to get an analytical solution when specifying only *some* of the parameters, though.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. I'll see what I can do. Thank you for the help.